# How to inject custom singleton bean in E4 application?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

Can someone please explain me how to use Eclipse E4 DI feature to inject my custom services/providers?.

```
@Singleton
public class ConnectionPool {
  // should be a singleton
}

public class MyService implements IMyService {
    @Inject
    ConnectionPool pool;
}

// referenced in application model
public class SamplePart {

    @Inject
    IMyService myService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
       myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Or is it possible to use Google Guice (for example) together with Eclipse DI?

I tried few examples (like [this](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-40-inject-your-own)) but it's not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `@Creatable` annotation to `ConnectionPool` (`org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Creatable`):

```
@Singleton
@Creatable
public class ConnectionPool
```

You could also use an OSGi service for the service. It is also possible to create the service in an AddOn or in the the application LifeCycle class. You can also use a `ContextFunction` to create a service.